# curl apis doesn't change values when dns is up and down but curl command gives success/fail output

Tags: c++, curl, dns

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;



string gettimenow()
{
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
        struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
        std::ostringstream stm ;
        stm << (now->tm_year + 1900)<<"-"
             << (now->tm_mon + 1)<<"-"
             <<  now->tm_mday<<"-"
             << now->tm_hour<<"-"
             <<now->tm_min<<"-"
             <<now->tm_sec;
        return stm.str();
}


// proxyURL - http://web-proxy.ind.hp.com
//exampleURL - https://example.com
int main()
{
    string cmd = "curl -k  -x proxyURL:8080 -L exampleURL --connect-timeout 10";
    string output ="";
    string errorout = "";

    int i =0;
    while ( i< 50){
        cout<< "value i ="<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"sss 35 "<<gettimenow()<<endl;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
      CURLcode res;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "EXAMPLEURL");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,"proxyURL");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,8080);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10L);
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      if(res != CURLE_OK){
          cout<<"CURL failed with error ::"<<curl_easy_strerror(res)<<endl;
      }else
          cout<<"CURL api success "<<endl;
    }
    sleep(60);
    i++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When run program if DNS is configured properly the curl api gives success and it continue to give success if remove DNS entries. 
The cmd "curl -k  -x proxyURL:8080 -L exampleURL --connect-timeout 10" gives proper output like when DNS is down it says

[root@sek1d2dbld ~]# curl -k  -x proxyURL:8080 -L exampleURL --connect-timeout 10
curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'web-proxy.ind.hp.com'
If DNS is properly configured then output is displayed.

Please suggest how to resolve this problem appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 1):

libcurl caches resolved names. By default, it keeps them for 60 seconds.

You can disable the DNS cache by using `curl_easy_setopt` to set the `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` option to 0.

Note that some libc implementations also have their own internal cache of name server information; if disabling the libcurl cache doesn't work, you may need to tell your libc to update it's name server. I believe `res_init` does this.

Comment: Since he is doing repeated curl invokes, curl's own caching cannot be blamed here however since it won't survive between invokes. And even res_init() won't help. This seems like DNS/resolver problem.

Comment: I was under the impression the DNS cache is per handle, not per perform invocation.

Comment: I have tried CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT option but it doesn't work. The problem I would like to address network up/down issue in my program. DNS is one example for any reason If I am not able to connect to specified URL I should report at that time it is not connecting after say 10 min it is again connected. I am trying to simulate the situation using DNS entries removal and addition.

Comment: The solution to above problem is use a worked thread and do the job and join back. It is working but may not be a ideal solution.